# field ‘value’ has incomplete type

Tags: c++, class, compilation

I have a C++ interdependence problem and i can not understand where the problem is...

Here are my headers:

json.array.h

```
#ifndef __JSON_ARRAY__
#define __JSON_ARRAY__

#include "json.object.h"

class JSON_OBJECT;

/* JSON_ARRAY */
class JSON_ARRAY {
    int size;
    custom_list<JSON_OBJECT> * container;

...
};

#endif
```

json.object.h

```
#ifndef __JSON_OBJECT__
#define __JSON_OBJECT__

#include "hash.h"
#include "elem_info.h"
#include "json.type.h"

class JSON_TYPE;
class elem_info;

/* JSON_OBJECT */
class JSON_OBJECT {
    custom_list<elem_info> *H;
    int HMAX;
    unsigned int (*hash) (std::string);
...
};

#endif
```

json.type.h

```
#ifndef __JSON_TYPE__
#define __JSON_TYPE__

#include "json.object.h"
#include "json.array.h"

class JSON_OBJECT;
class JSON_ARRAY;

class JSON_TYPE {
    JSON_ARRAY * _JSON_ARRAY_;
    JSON_OBJECT * _JSON_OBJECT_;
    std::string _JSON_OTHER_;
    std::string _JSON_TYPE_;
...
};

#endif
```

elem_info.h

```
#ifndef __ELEM_INFO__
#define __ELEM_INFO__

#include "json.type.h"
class JSON_TYPE;

class elem_info {
public:
    std::string key;
    JSON_TYPE value;
...
}; 

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "custom_list.h" // it inculdes cpp also
#include "json.type.h"
#include "elem_info.h"
#include "json.object.h"
#include "json.array.h"
#include "json.type.cpp"
#include "elem_info.cpp"
#include "json.object.cpp"
#include "json.array.cpp"


int main()
{
    JSON_ARRAY * root = new JSON_ARRAY;
    JSON_OBJECT obj;
    JSON_OBJECT obj1;
    JSON_OBJECT * obj2 = new JSON_OBJECT;
    JSON_TYPE * type = new JSON_TYPE;
...
}
```

When i try to compile my code, i have this error:

> elem_info.h:10:15: error: field ‘value’ has incomplete type
>        JSON_TYPE value;

It looks like it cant find JSON_TYPE. I cant understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have a forward declaration here

```
class JSON_TYPE;

class elem_info {
public:
    std::string key;
    JSON_TYPE value;
...
};
```

But `value` is an instance of `JSON_TYPE`. You can only forward declare if you have members that are pointers or references, not actual instances.

In fact, since you have a full include before that forward declaration, you don't need the forward declaration at all, and as I said it wouldn't help you anyway. You'd be fine with:

```
#ifndef __ELEM_INFO__
#define __ELEM_INFO__

#include "json.type.h"

class elem_info {
public:
    std::string key;
    JSON_TYPE value;
...
}; 

#endif
```

Comment: Except not because he has circular includes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do:

```
class JSON_TYPE;

class elem_info {
public:
    std::string key;
    JSON_TYPE value;
...
};
```

`JSON_TYPE` is an incomplete type.  You can have a pointer or reference but no actual instance since the compiler does not know what it is.

Comment: Not true. He included the full definition immediately before the [redundant] forward declaration. -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I just noticed there are a lot more issues than what I put.  Should this just be deleted?

Comment: Consider it solved. I changed all my methods. Now, with pointers it works. Thanks again, Nathan.

Answer (score 1):

`json.type.h` includes `json.array.h` which includes `json.object.h` which includes `json.type.h`.

That can't work.